# Can you pick up a monster spawner with silk touch?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I made a base on top of a zombie dungeon with ladders leading up. And i'm trying to get another spawner next to it without changing to creative, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to get a spawner in survival, not even with a silk touch pickaxe.

One time a creeper blew up a monster spawner and it actually dropped and I was able to pick it up. I have not been able to reproduce this, though it may be possible in your version, we use different versions. I suggest testing this in creative mode in a test world.

[More on Monster Spawners](https://www.digminecraft.com/decoration_recipes/make_monster_spawner.php)

If you have cheats available to you, then you can use the `/setblock` command, or the `/clone` command to either make one, or to clone the one that you already have. It looks like you probably do not have cheats available to you in this case.